# grep for entries that do not contain a backtick before and after a regexp

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

I have a text file with the following content:

```
Read the `lmn(7)` man page but not qrs(6).
* abc(1)
* `efg(3)`
* `ijk(1)`
* xyz(5)
```

I want now to filter for all lines that contain a man page name that is not in backticks? The expected output is:

```
Read the `lmn(7)` man page but not qrs(6).
* abc(1)
* xyz(5)
```

For demonstration purposes, I need this as a single grep command and not with other tools or piped.

I tried the following, but it only returns the first line:

```
$ egrep '[^`][a-z]*\([0-9]\)[^`]'
```

Comment: `^[^\`]+$` should suffice. https://regex101.com/r/kw9BU3/1

Comment: How about: `grep -v '^\\*.*\`\`` ' Input_file` one? This worked for me with shown samples.

Comment: Sorry formatting issue with backtick in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't match the other lines because there's no character after the `)` to match `` [^`] ``. You need to add an alternative to match the end of the line. And you should have a similar alternative for the first backtick to match the beginning of the line.

```
grep -E '(^|[^`])[a-z]*\([0-9]\)([^`]|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `grep -v` should work for with the given examples:

```bash
grep -v '^\* `' file

Read the `lmn(7)` man page but not qrs(6).
* abc(1)
* xyz(5)
```

We are just filtering out lines that start with `` * ` `` using `grep -v`.

Answer (score 0):

If these matches occur without a backtick between the match and the end of the string:

```
grep -E '[^`][a-z]*\([0-9]\)[^`]*$' file
```

Output

```
Read the `lmn(7)` man page but not qrs(6).
* abc(1)
* xyz(5)
```